# Unable to add title attribute to link in CKEditor5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I need to add title attribute to link in CKEditor5 e.g.:

link

I tried to define new decorator, add extraAllowedContent:'a[title]' property and also extend schema and add conversion, but no luck. I use CKEditor5 with React.

Thank you